# How to execute a program in linux after compiling it?

Tags: c, linux

I am compiling a C code in linux with the following command:

```
gcc -o myprogram myprogram.c
```

If I hadn't given a name to it,  I could have simply written the command `./a.out` to execute it. But now, to execute the program I just write "myprogram" to the command line, but it says "command not found". What can I do to execute it?

Comment: Current working directory is not on the path.

Comment: You really should take the habit of compiling with `gcc -Wall -g myprogram.c -o myprogram` then learn how to use `make` with your `Makefile`. You'll also need to learn how to use the `gdb` debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible that the current directory ("`.`") isn't on your `PATH`. (You can check this by typing `echo $PATH`, this is a list of directories delimited with" `:`". "`.`" should be in the list if you want to run something in the current directory.)

If the current directory isn't on your `PATH`, you'll need to type `./myprogram` (or whatever the correct path is).

Answer (score 2):

```
./myprogram
```

should do the trick.

(But really... have you looked at the contents of the directory after compiling the program "without name"? Or do you think `./a.out` is a magic sequence Bash recognizes?)

Comment: @bigO - FYI, the answer above works assuming that you're in the same directory as `myprogram`. Otherwise, `/path/to/myprogram` will also work.

Comment: @bigO Please have a general idea about computers and the OS you're using before starting programming, else you'll shoot yourself and others in the foot.

Comment: @bigO if you just type "myprogram", the shell will look in it's standard directories for executables, like /bin and /usr/bin. You need to specify the location, e.g., "./"