# Linux doesn't want run a compiled file

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile

I create a parser engine for Gold Parser, improving an existing one adding whole support for UTF-8 or UNICODE and error handling. And I want make it available also on Linux and therefore I want test it on Linux and at the same time improve my skills with this SO(Ubuntu 22) and learn Makefile.

In hurry for ask this question on Stack Overflow I uploaded all on  [github](https://github.com/jurhas/mparser).  The library is `mparser`, `main` contains the test functions and `dhash` is my tool for the debug(just checks the memory leaks) I included `dhash`  so I have a more complicated scenario to learn Makefile.

What is the problem: It does not run on Linux. I copied the Makefile from this site [Make tutorial](https://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/), after I understood it closely 80%
I did some changes to run with my project, it is available on GitHub but I post it also here:

```
IDIR =include
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-I$(IDIR)

ODIR=obj
LDIR =../lib

LIBS=-lm

_DEPS = dhash.h mparser.h
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))
FDEPS =$(_DEPS)

_OBJ =  mparser.o dhash.o main.o 
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))


$(ODIR)/%.o: %.c $(FDEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

mparser: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o *~ core $(INCDIR)/*~
```

In Linux I added the current directory `.` to the path  as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072753/how-to-execute-a-program-in-linux-after-compiling-it).

I run `file mparser` and it says:

```
mparser: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=7b91119ab5e7a335c16c61c883ad5092da23eab5, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped
```

So there is the magic word `executable` as suggested [here](https://unix.stac). But if I launch `mparser` it says denied access. I tried also with whole path, `/media/jurhas/INTENSO/mparser`, and doesn't work either.

How can I run my program on Linux after I compiled it?

Edit:

[image: The shell]

Comment: Please paste the entire error message. (Come on, you have a wall of text with pleasantries and background information, but didn't include the most important thing. You should've started with "I compiled and executable, but when I run it, I get such-and-such error", and then everything else.)

Comment: My crystal ball says you need `chmod +x /media/jurhas/INTENSO/mparser`.

Comment: Please copy and paste the build command with output and the command you're using to run the file with output.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'm also wondering what the mount options are for `/media/jurhas/INTENSO/mparser`.  `noexec`, perhaps?

Comment: I don't get much errors, it just says "Permesso Negato" in italian, that means not allowed, I post the picture of the shall, just a second

Comment: @ Andrew Henle : How can I see it and how can I change it? It seems the right way...

Comment: @SanPei Run `mount | grep media`.  If the output contains `noexec`, the executable won't run.

Comment: Yep it was the right way, I moved it on Documents now works. Thanks, Excuse me, but they are my very first steps with Linux

Comment: *"it just says "Permesso Negato""* Nah, it says more than that. It's better to always post the complete error.

Comment: Please don't post images into questions in StackOverflow.  Instead cut and paste the text into the question, with proper formatting.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714)

Comment: Why did you not test the code before you started making your changes?

Comment: Putting the `.` in your path is bad advice, likely to cause you more problems than it solves.  If you want to execute a file in the current directory then you should say so explicitly (`./file_to_execute`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

": Permission denied" when trying to execute something much always means about linux file permissions.

You are trying to "execute" a file on a Linux filesystem that does not have the executable flag.

Here is the simplest way to view if a file is executable:

```
user@host:~$ ls -lah file.txt 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser myusergroup 0 Jan 23 13:37 file.txt
```

You want to look at this: `-rw-rw-r--`

It states:

- first characters (-): the dash means its a file (and, for example, not a directory)
- char 2-4 (rw-): the owner of the file (myuser) is allowed to read (r) write (w) and NOT execute (-) the file
- char 5-6 (rw-): the group of the file (myusergroup) is allowed to read (r) write (w) and NOT execute (-) the file
- chat 7-8 (r--): everyone who is not the owner of the file (myuser) or in the group that owns the file (myusergroup) is ONLY allowed to read (r) and NOT allowed to write or execute (--) the file

`rw-rw-r--` is the default for most Linux distributions.

What you want to do is make your file executable. There are a number of ways for that.

## chmod +x

```
# before
user@host:~$ ls -lha file.txt 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 0 Jan 23 13:37 file.txt

# give everyone executable permissions
user@host:~$ chmod +x file.txt 

# after
user@host:~$ ls -lha file.txt 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 0 Jan 23 13:37 file.txt
```

Now EVERYONE can execute your file. This is most likely not what you want.

## chmod u+x

```
user@host:~$ ls -lha file.txt 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 0 Jan 23 13:41 file.txt
user@host:~$ chmod u+x file.txt 
user@host:~$ ls -lha file.txt 
-rwxrw-r-- 1 user user 0 Jan 23 13:41 file.txt
```

You can use `u+x` as argument to chmod to give ONLY the user that owns the file execute permissions.

If this does not help try `mount | grep noexec`. If your file is located in a filesystem that is mounted with noexec, you are unable to execute files in there. You can update your `/etc/fstab` (the file that lists whats to be mounted on boot), remove the noexec and remount the directory using `mount -o remount /path/to/mounted/dir`

Comment: "*`rw-rw-r--` is the default for most Linux distributions*" -- sort of, maybe.  In my experience, the default umask is more often 0022 (which would tend to yield `rw-r--r--`) than 0002 (which would tend to yield your `rw-rw-r--`).  But that's mostly moot, because compilers generate executables having execute permission, so `rwxr-xr-x` or `rwxr-x---`, for example.

Comment: thats an option too (the tool you're using, in this case a compiler, changing the permissions after creation).
The default for your particular linux distro is defined in the `umask` (google that)

Comment: "*The default for your particular linux distro is defined in the `umask`*" -- again, sort of.  That's framed weirdly.  Yes, the umask in effect modulates the permissions of new files you create.  Linux distros ordinarily set a umask in their global shell configuration files, and it is *this*, the umask value itself, that can be interpreted as a default, not any particular set of resulting file permissions.  Moreover, the umask is a *user* parameter.  If you don't like the default then you can easily change it for your own shell sessions.

Comment: yes true, but more info than he will understand :P

Comment: Perhaps.  But it is nevertheless important to understand that, contrary to this answer's apparent claim, there is no one set of default permissions.  Initial permissions on file creation result from combining the requested permissions with the umask in effect, which is why compilers don't have to do anything much special to generate executables with execute permission.  The OP could have a screwed-up umask, but if not, and in particular if they are using the system's default umask, then the permissions problem this answer talks about is very unlikely to be relevant.

Comment: jup, correct. +1